# Python: Get the redirect urls using cURL

Tags: python, curl, pycurl

I am interested in getting the intermediate URLs in a redirect chain using pycURL. So, say I have a website, **Site A**, which redirects to **Site B**, which then redirects to **Site C**. Regularly I would only be able to see **Site A** (the starting URL) and **Site C** (the ending URL), however I am also interested in any sites that happen to reside in between the starting and ending site (in this case **Site B**). How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look to PyCurl [Callbacks](http://pycurl.sourceforge.net/doc/callbacks.html):

```
## Callback function invoked when header data is ready
def header(buf):
    import sys
    sys.stdout.write(buf)
    # Returning None implies that all bytes were written

c = pycurl.Curl()
c.setopt(pycurl.URL, "http://www.siteA.com/")
c.setopt(pycurl.HEADERFUNCTION, header)
c.perform()
```